# azure node.js request, response - seeking some clarification

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile services-NodeJS backend, and when programming it, I always face this doubt - let me explain using the below code snippet

```js
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function addUserToDB(request, response){
  ///some code here
  var theUser = request.user;

  ///get the user's entity object
  try {
    objAppUser = buildAppUserEntityObj(theUser, request); //for simplicity sake, lets say this is not asynchronous function
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log ('error in addUserToDB when calling buildAppUserEntityObj');  //****????****
    request.respond(statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST, err);
    return; // ##????## is a 'return' needed here to avoid the execution of the code below,  or should I assume that the function will return once request is responded (request.respond) in above line.
  }

  ....code to add userEntity to DB
  //some more code in case of successful try above, can I assume there is no way this code will be reached in case of error in the above try-catch
  //       ofcourse I can move this code in the 'try' block above, but I am just trying to understand what happens if above try ends in catch block for some reason and there is no 'return' at the end that catch block.
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function buildAppUserEntityObj(user, request) {
  if ( user.level === 'anonymous' ) { //ideally this would be called in above function, but I am putting this here just to throw an example.
    console.error('Anonymous User' );
    request.respond(statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST, message);  //will this request.respond will send the response to client immediately, or will it be passed on as error the try-catch of above 'addUserToDB' function 
    return; // ##????## also, is 'return' needed here to avoid the execution of the code below, 
  }

  ....code to build a User entity object based on some business logic
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I guess, it all boils down to three questions: 
1. Is 'return' needed in the two places (marked by ##????## in the above two functions? 
2. Will the message (marked by //****????**** ) be logged in case user.level === 'anonymous' 
3. request.respond vs response.send , whats the difference?

I believe these doubts are because of my lack of thorough expressJS knowledge, so while I am going thru azure/express.js documentation again, I thought I would throw my doubt here to the expert community to get a more clear explanation.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First

In the second `return` (insode of `buildAppUserEntityObj` function, I believe you want it to be:

```
throw new Error("Anonymous user is not allowed")
```

Otherwise, even if user is anonymous, your `catch` code will never execute anyway.

---

You need the first `return;`, otherwise it will continue executing the code below.

### Second

Message will be logged, if you fix the code described in *First* paragraph.

### Third

There is no `request.respond` in standard Node.js [http module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html). Can you clarify, what module are you using? That module's API shall answer your question anyway.

Comment: thanks alandarev, I believe request.respond is coming from azure module, I picked it from azure mobile services documentation. But let's say I replace it by response.send, in the 'buildAppUserEntityObj' function, will I still need a 'return' after that? I mean, what I am thinking is instead of 'throw new err' as you suggested, if I call response.send there, will the response be sent to the client immediately with no further server-side code execution, so no need for me to throw err to pass on to first function.

Comment: No, the code execute will continue, even if response is sent... Furthermore if response is sent and closed, the further code might raise a socket exception complaining that it is closed prematurely.